# Solidity, Remix IDE- Warning:Unused Local Variable

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I am trying to import the 'SimpleStorage' file...

```js
pragma solidity  ^0.8.0; 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "SimpleStorage.sol";

contract FactoryStorage {
    function createSimpleContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you refer to the correct file name.
If the file is in the same folder, you just have to import with the dot-dash before.

As so:   `import "SimpleStorage.sol";`

Comment: When I use ....import "./SimpleStorage.sol";  The box turned red and said- 'not found foldername/SimpleStorage.sol- Then I erased "./"and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

A warning just means that there might be something in the code that you overlooked, it is not an error. In your case, it is just the simpleStorage that you have created and haven't used un any way yet. Once you use it in the code the warning will disappear.